# Cant find class in uber jar

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, jar, hortonworks-data-platform

*I am on Hortonworks Distribution 2.4 (effectively hadoop 2.7.1 and spark 1.6.1)*

---

I am packaging my own version of spark in the uber jar (2.1.0) while cluster is on 1.6.1. In the process, i am sending all required libraries through a fat jar (built using maven - uber jar concept).

However, spark submit (through spark 2.1.0 client) fails citing NoClassFound Error on jersey client.  Upon listing my uber jar contents, i can see the exact class file in the jar, still spark/yarn cant find it.

here goes - 
The error message -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/api/client/config/ClientConfig
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.TimelineClient.createTimelineClient(TimelineClient.java:55)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl.createTimelineClient(YarnClientImpl.java:181)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl.serviceInit(YarnClientImpl.java:168)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.submitApplication(Client.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:156)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:509)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2313)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:868)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:860)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:860)
```

And here is my attempt to find the class in jar file -

```
jar -tf uber-xxxxx-something.jar | grep jersey | grep ClientCon
com/sun/jersey/api/client/ComponentsClientConfig.class
com/sun/jersey/api/client/config/ClientConfig.class
```

... Other files

what could be going on here ? Suggestions ? ideas please..

**EDIT**
the jersey client section of the pom goes here -

```
    <dependency>
         <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
         <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
         <version>1.19.3</version>
     </dependency>
```

**EDIT**
I also wanted to indicate this, that my code is compiled with Scala 2.12 with compatibility level set to 2.11.  However, the cluster is perhaps on 2.10.  I am saying perhaps since I believe that cluster nodes dont necessarily have to have Scala binaries installed; YARN just launches the components' jar/class files without using Scala binaries.  wonder if thats playing a role here !!!

Comment: From the [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html): "*To review per-container launch environment, increase yarn.nodemanager.delete.debug-delay-sec to a large value (e.g. 36000), and then access the application cache through yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs on the nodes on which containers are launched. This directory contains the launch script, JARs, and all environment variables used for launching each container. This process is useful for debugging classpath problems in particular.*"

Comment: What is your hadoop version ? Also provide please your pom with jersey-client version,

Comment: @Vidya - I checked that component, however, my application submission request is not hitting executors yet. It somehow fails much earlier during driver initiation itself. Effectively, submit call itself is failing.

Comment: @FaigB - I am on Hortonworks Distribution 2.4 (effectively hadoop 2.7.1 and spark 1.6.1) Already added jersey client POM.xml in question - edit.